# Not defined error when attempting to dynamically load scripts with React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

For the project I'm working on I've made a React app that's based around displaying information whenever a country is clicked. I'm using an SVG world map from simplemaps.com (https://simplemaps.com/custom/world) which comes with javascript hooks to handle user clicks, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   simplemaps_worldmap.hooks.click_state = function(id){
     alert(simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata.state_specific[id].name);
   }
</script>
```

In order to display the map you must also include

```
<script src="./scripts/mapdata.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/worldmap.js"></script>
```

and

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Rendering the div component is handled by a React component I made, but this meant that the map stopped being displayed when I clicked onto a different page and clicked back. To solve this I started dynamically loading the scripts as part of the React component like so:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

function Map() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const mapScript = document.createElement('script');
        const worldScript = document.createElement('script');
        const clickScript = document.createElement('script');
    
        mapScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        mapScript.src = '../scripts/mapdata.js';

        worldScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        worldScript.src = '../scripts/worldmap.js';

        clickScript.type = "text/javascript";
        clickScript.innerHTML = `simplemaps_worldmap.hooks.click_state = function(id){
            alert(simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata.state_specific[id].name);
        }`;
    
        document.head.appendChild(mapScript);
        document.head.appendChild(worldScript);
        document.body.appendChild(clickScript);
    
        return () => {
            document.head.removeChild(mapScript);
            document.head.removeChild(worldScript);
            document.body.removeChild(clickScript);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="map">
        </div>
    )
}

export default Map;
```

Initially it worked, but after I added the clickScript lines:

```
const clickScript = document.createElement('script');

clickScript.type = "text/javascript";
clickScript.innerHTML = `simplemaps_worldmap.hooks.click_state = function(id){
    alert(simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata.state_specific[id].name);
};`

document.body.appendChild(clickScript);
    
return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(clickScript);
}
```

I started getting the error: `ReferenceError: simplemaps_worldmap is not defined`.
It works as intended when loaded in the HTML page like so:

```
<script src="./scripts/mapdata.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/worldmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   simplemaps_worldmap.hooks.click_state = function(id){
     alert(simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata.state_specific[id].name);
   }
</script>
```

However when it's being dynamically loaded it seems to break it. I have tried loading them in both the head and the body and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

To sum up the problem: the scripts work fine when done in HTML but when loaded in javascript the clickScript can't seem to find mapData.js to reference it, even though worldData.js can find mapData.js. I've tried making clickScript external, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Apologies if this is an obvious fix but any help would be appreciated.

Edit: [My index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U15Ml.png), [My map.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewoeH.png)

Comment: "when I clicked onto a different page and clicked back" - What do you mean by clicked back? is the page being reloaded, or is it a Single Page Application?

Comment: @RichardHunter It's a Single Page Application, I use react router dom for navigating between the 'pages'. When I click to another 'page' and click back the map wouldn't render. It would render if I refreshed the webpage but I've been trying to avoid that to make it look seamless.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the SimpleMaps script, on page load, looks for the `id="map"` element and renders a map into it. But when you re-render the component, it does, of course get deleted, (because you're rendering an empty div). So really what you want to do is force SimpleMaps to reinitialise. Reloading the scripts is unnecessary since they are already there. Does simplemaps not have some method for reinitialising?

Comment: I see a `simplemaps_worldmap.load()` method in the documentation. https://simplemaps.com/docs/api .You could try that in the useEffect() hook.

Comment: This as well may be useful. It's probably a good idea to load the map manually instead of allowing SimpleMap to handle things. https://simplemaps.com/docs/load-manually

Comment: I think I understand, so I've moved the scripts to the index.html and now they work as expected, but the loading problem is back. So now I need to load it manually like from useEffect, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that. When I try to it says that: 'simplemaps_worldmap' is not defined. I try to import it, but it won't let me import something from public as I'm in src, or vice versa. I can't do the hook in the HTML either, because then it won't load correctly. Sorry I'm new to React this might be obvious but how can I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Once you load the scripts with script tags at the top of `index.html`, simplemaps_worldmap *should* be there. Try doing small steps at a time: Check without React, that the variable exists. Then try to console.log it out in the useEffect hook. If it is, then try calling `load()` on it as explained in the answer below.

Comment: @RichardHunter For some reason it's still giving me the not defined error. I've included screenshots as an edit at the bottom of the original post above, hopefully they might point out something that's going wrong. Either way I think it's possible to get it working from here with URI Fragments and an onhashchange listener in the index.html. I would prefer to do it the way that you suggested however, because it sounds much simpler, if you have any ideas as to how to fix it - many thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have to emphasise that my 'solution' really is just a guess. I could easily have got it completely wrong. That said:  In the head of your index.html, you're using the `simplemaps_worldmap` variable without an error, yet you get one later when you try to access the same variable? That seems weird. Check that `simplemaps_worldmap` in the header is not undefined, then try and work out at what point it becomes undefined.

Comment: @RichardHunter It's finally working! I've managed to reload the graph with URL hashes and the "onhashchange" attribute in HTML, so it's all functional. Many thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Delighted to hear it. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleMaps script, after page load, looks for the `id="map"` element and renders a map into it. When you re-render the component, the map gets deleted, (because you're rendering an empty div). So really, what you want to do is force SimpleMaps to reinitialise the map. Reloading the scripts is unnecessary since they are already there.

I am unable to create a working version because I don't have a license for SimpleMaps, but this is how I might approach it, basing this on what I read in the [docs](https://simplemaps.com/docs/load-manually) about manual loading.

In mapdata.js

```
main_settings.auto_load='no';
```

In the React component:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

function Map() {

    useEffect(() => {
      
      simplemaps_worldmap.load();

    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="map"></div>
    )
}

export default Map;
```